# incorrect information in patent

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [WO2009094726A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2009094726A1)

the patent claims that:
"Finally the ScCDUP gene was amplified with the primers SEQ ID NO: 91 and SEQ ID NO: 92 from the plasmid pHHT-CDUP-ΔPF1 1_0037 (Maier et al. (2006) Molecular & Biochemical Parasitology 150, 118-121 ) and cloned Xho I/Xma I into the cut pDC-1 to replace the HsTK gene with the ScCDUP gene."

There is no mention of a plasmid named pHHT-CDUP-ΔPF1 1_0037 in the cited reference.  The cited reference is similarly unreliable in describing construction of the plasmids mentioned therein

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! I've closed your question as a duplicate of a previous source for information on correcting information in patents. If the linked question does not fully answer your question, I would appreciate if you could [edit] your post to make clearer what you'd like us to answer. Let me know if you have any questions on this or if I can help in any way.